# How to find dynamically generated data using AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, node.js, file-upload, angularjs-directive, image-upload

I need to upload an image in my AngularJS, NodeJS application.

I have the following element on my page for selecting an image in a form using the Bootstrap File Input plugin:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/512x512/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=NO+IMAGE" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select image </span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change </span>
        <input type="file" name="..." >
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data inside the following div gets changes once an image has been selected:

```
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail">
</div>
```

It becomes to something like following:

```
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAA3=...">
</div>
```

I need the `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAA3=...` data of the selected image for it to upload to a directory on my server using NodeJS.

Could somebody help me with an AngularJS directive to get that data?

Comment: So you really only want to upload the generated thumbnail and not the actual image file they selected?

Comment: @mscdex: Hmm.. I actually thought that the data contained in the `<img>` tag was for the whole image. How could I find the data for the whole image if the data in the `<img>` tag is not for the whole image?

Comment: That was just a guess since the `<div>` has a class of `thumbnail`. However you could upload the file using a standard `enctype=multipart/form-data` form submit or use xhr to send the form using the `FormData` API.